# Can I substitute SICP lecture videos with SICP lecture notes?

Tags: lisp, sicp

As far as I understand, the famous SICP lecture *videos*:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/

Are a complementary material to the famous SICP book.

However, for a few reasons, I prefer reading these SICP lecture *notes* from here:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/lecture-notes/

So, a couple of questions to those who know SICP:

1). Can I substitute SICP lecture *videos* with SICP lecture *notes*?

1.1). Do these lecture notes cover the same material as the videos?

1.2). How were those notes made: by going through the videos or from another source? Because if they were made by going through the videos, then they are for the first edition of the book and thus outdated.

1.3). Who made those notes and why did they use "close-enuf?"-instead-of-"good-enough?"  style of writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.0 You can. Personally I love the original videos and the transcript are not the same as the lecture notes you linked to but they will teach you some Scheme.

1.1 They seem to be more modern than that 80's video with the wizards themselves.

1.2 SICP was a standard course as an introduction to computer science. There are numerous universities that taught them and they have similar but not identical content. I believe I've seen newer videos had several sessions of tree traversal so the different teachers picked the stuff they liked from the book to focus on.

1.3 Your guess is a good as mine. The essence of the two names are meant to represent the same idea, but `close-enuf?` is perhaps more concrete since we're talking about aproximiations and numbers while talking about good numbers might give people the idea that some numbers might be evil.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is great, you accurately addressed every point, even kept the structure. Funnily enouGH, I've never noticed the problem of 'good' vs 'close', I was worried about 'enough' vs 'enuf', it sounded childish to me.
Please also consider another question of mine about SICP: "What are the prerequisites for SICP?".
Link: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/267548/what-are-the-prerequisites-for-sicp